# how to set django development server

Tags: python, django, django-dev-server, django-deployment

I am stuck on this step:

i have a page, which i am developing in django. the page is ready to test. i deployed it. running well and it is online. but now i want to setup a new project in server as the testing version of what is online now. I went to control panel of my hosting provider and saw that once i created the django project first, it also created a new `dev.mypage.com`. But i cannot find this in my server. i dont know how to setup a new dev project in server so that i can develop locally, push to test project and test online and then go live.

please help

Comment: So you basically want to host multiple django servers on the same virtual machine ?

Comment: @karthikr, honestly i dont have experience with virtual machines. I have a django hosting service from provider and they provide me django installation on server so that i can run my django wegpage. they set production one in lighttpd and development one in development server. what i want to know is how to set thet dev server and get my development proj running

Comment: You can install nginx, and have that point to 2 different servers. There is lots of information available online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to use nginx + gunicorn (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html). Also, http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/ is useful.

Comment: thanks, but i found different solution, otherwise your suggestion would be the solution ;)